# Generate Certificate From RootCA Based On .CSR FIle

Tags: powershell, ssl, certificate-authority

AS part of a project ongoing, I have been asked to create a PowerShell script that will take a bulk load of.CSR file, upload them to my Internally used Root Signing Certificate Authority and produce the signed certificate.

The Templates are setup and working - and at the minute, if I want to generate a certificate, I have to upload the manually a. CSR file to the localhost/certsrv/ and then go to the application, sign and export. Laborious project.

I have come across the Get-Certificate command in Powershell - but I cannot seem to the point that a .CSR file?  Help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Using PowerShell, (or your scripting language of choice, but I like PS) you can invoke the CertReq.exe command to sign a certificate request as such:

```
certreq -submit <Path to request file> <Path to output cert file>
```

So for bulk you could...

```
$CSRs = Get-ChildItem C:\CertificateRequests
$OutPath = New-Item C:\IssuedCertificates -ItemType Directory -Force
ForEach($CSR in $CSRs){
    $FileOut = Join-Path $OutPath "$($CSR.BaseName).cer"
    CertReq -submit $CSR.FullName $FileOut
}
```